# Stuck in Codecademy's Javascript fizzbuzz app

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

Here are Codecademy's instructions:

> Print out the numbers from 1 - 20.
>
> For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".
>
> For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".
>
> For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in the
>   console.
>
> Otherwise, just print out the number.

And here is my code:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else if (i % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");    
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
    else {
    console.log(i);    
    }
}
```

The problem is that it won't print "FizzBuzz" for the number 15. It just prints "Fizz".

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should consider what it means for a number to be divisible by 15. Taking into account that 3 and 5 are factors of 15.

Comment: Yes, you should read out your logic in simple terms - if i is divisible by 3, then Fizz, if i isn't divisible by 3, check if i is divisible by 5, then Buzz, if i is not divisible by 3 and is not divisible by 5, check if i is divisible by 3 and 5 ... hence your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The else if only runs if all of the other statements so far have been false. Since i % 3 is true, the remaing else/if statements will never run. Try something like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
    else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");    
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else {
        console.log(i);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a nested conditional this seems to work.

```
for ( i=1 ; i < 21 ; i++){
    if(i % 3 === 0) {
        if(i % 5 === 0){
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Fizz");
        }
    }
    else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        if ( i % 3 === 0){
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Buzz");
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

straight forward fizzBuzz in javascript using tenary operators(a one-line shorthand for an if-else statement) 
to learn about tenary operators go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var i = 1;
while (i <= 20){
    console.log((i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) ? "FizzBuzz" : (i % 3 === 0) ? "Fizz" : (i % 5 === 0 ? "Buzz" : i));
    i++;
}
```